# problem with the real time capturing of a video-android

Tags: android

```
   I need a big help for this  issue...
   I am not sure what i am doing is correct or not

   i am doing a sample application for transfering realtime video
```

from one android device to an emulator,
in device side i can open video cam and a set an output file for it,
while the recording is progressing, at the same time i am open a file
stream and reading all the content  by bytes with respect to
avilablity, and writing a socket which is communication with the
emulator. At the emulator side i am writing this to another file

When i click the recording stop button, i read the rest of the file
from the device side and writing to socket stream.
When i check the file size at the both side it is same

But i cannot play the file at the emulator is side when i check with
vlc, in the device side i can play recorded 3gp file

So my doubt, same file i cannot access at the same time when one
thread(android camera) is writing to the file

or it will correupt?

please help me.......... i

Answer (score 0):

Might this be a missing header problem?

Just on top of my head: Something might happen when the recording session has ended - like writing meta-stuff to the file etc.. It might be a wild guess...

I know there are applications out there doing pretty much what you are describing - but just with a little tweak. What I've seen so far has been live streaming apps that set up a server on the device. That might be the way to go about this.